# VBA EXCEL vlookups through all sheets vs index

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with over 200 sheets + index sheet, and I am trying to go through all sheets to copy data from index sheet. For example, I have the below table:

```
A   test1
B   test2
C   test3
D   test4
```

So I would like to do a vlookup in the index sheet, and copy the column K into the right sheet. For example, I would like "test1" to be copied in sheet "A", in cell A3. The table to vlookup is in sheet "INDEX", range J1:K4.
Is that possible? I stored a file [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b2e390323cb19bd0df7962616e7de07a20210113160017/39eb37e631ee698dec1c62d961df9eed20210113160104/9dd314)! For confidentiality reason, I've edited sheet names and content, and put a shorter file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I could attach a file, but I didnt find how to do so". Did you google?
 
Can you follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not sure if vlookup is the best way to do it in reality, this is what came in my mind when I thought how to do it.. I've edited with a link for a file I've stored, maybe it will be more clear.

Comment: I want to have in the cell A3 of the appropriate worksheet, the value that is in column K from INDEX sheet. So for example, in sheet "A" in A3 will be written "test1". In sheet "B", still in A3, will be written "test2" and so on for all sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub updateWorksheets()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "INDEX"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "J1"
    Const dstAddress As String = "A3"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Data Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(FirstCellAddress).Resize(, 2)
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Find( _
            What:="*", _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Data Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Declare additional variables (to be used in the 'For Next' loop).
    Dim dst As Worksheet ' Current Destination Worksheet
    Dim i As Long ' Data Array Row Counter
    
    ' Loop through rows of Data Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        ' Use the value in the first column to try to create a reference
        ' to the worksheet i.e. check if the worksheet exists.
        Set dst = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dst = wb.Worksheets(Data(i, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' If the worksheet exists,...
        If Not dst Is Nothing Then
            ' ...write value from second column of Data Array
            ' to Destination Cell Range in Current Destination worksheet.
            dst.Range(dstAddress).Value = Data(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```